# Request to the local MavensMate server failed, please ensure MavensMate Desktop is installed

Tags: mavensmate, sublime

I'm getting the following error and could not able to resolve, so I uninstall sublime3 and remove the `c:\users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3` and restart my machine and install again the sublime3 and follow this [instructions](http://www.forcewizard.com/blog/installing-mavensmate-windows-lightning-support):

after doing all that I'm still getting the below error:

> Result: [ERROR]: Request to the local MavensMate server failed, please
>   ensure MavensMate Desktop is installed and running. For more
>   information, please visit
>   https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/tree/master/docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure the separate `MavensMate` application is *installed and running* in order to be able to save any files using `Sublime Text`. That's the tool that allows `Sublime Text` to communicate with the Salesforce servers.

[image: mavensmate-architecture]

You can see releases available to install [here](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-Desktop/releases), where there is also a **[<kbd>Latest Release</kbd>](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-Desktop/releases/latest)** button.

Comment: Which file I need to download from the link https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-Desktop/releases for windows ?